# The specified value is not an instance of type 'Edm.Decimal'\r\nParameter name: value

Tags: database, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, edmx

When I try to map numeric data type field of SQL Database with Edmx Entity's property as `Int16` using Visual Studio 2010 and then I try to add or update record in database table that having numeric data type, its give error message:

> The specified value is not an instance of type 'Edm.Decimal'
>   Parameter name: value.

But when I try to do same things using Visual Studio 2012 then Its works fine.

How can this problem be solved using Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to coding, but I had the exact same error. I was trying to pass a Int16 into a DB that was defined as "Number". Changing "int" into "decimal" for the value in question fixed that for me.